# D3.js: How can I give the same style to Top and Right line of a grid with the same style than grid lines?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm newbie with d3.js but I would like to remove or modify the style of these lines to the same color of grid lines?

[image]

I have created the gridline with this code:

```
    setGrid(canvas, scales){
    //Y Axis grid
    canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + OFFSET_LEFT + ", 0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(scales.yScale).tickSize(-(WIDTH - OFFSET_LEFT - OFFSET_RIGHT)).tickFormat(""));
    //X Axis grid
    canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + OFFSET_TOP + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(scales.xScale).tickSize((HEIGHT - OFFSET_BOTTOM - OFFSET_TOP)).tickFormat(""));
}
```

And I've the style with this css:

```
.grid line{
    stroke: blue;
}
```

Comment: @Jose_Carlos It would be really helpful if you provide working jsfiddle or stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style your axises you can append this code to yours:

```
.call(g => g.select('.domain').remove()) // removes the lines that make a square around the chart
.call(g =>
  g.selectAll('.YAxisLabel .tick:first-of-type line').attr('stroke', '#D4D4D4'), // append a style to line with ticks
);
```